# Liferay jsp page not found

Tags: jsp, liferay, portlet, liferay-ide

I've got a problem with redirecting to a jsp page.

```
    <portlet:renderURL var="DLMSnewSearch">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/view.jsp" />
</portlet:renderURL>
<p>
    <a href="<%=DLMSnewSearch%>">&larr; New Search</a>
</p>
```

Eclipse throws a warning: Type "/view.jsp" not found.

Exception thrown:

```
    00:38:09,048 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-140][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.view_jsp._jspService(view_jsp.java:716)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:331)
    at com.liferay.portlet.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:112)
    at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:371)
    at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.include(MVCPortlet.java:387)
```

It worked, until I reinstalled my Linux Mint and added Liferay project from existing source... This is a backup which I saved from previous Mint.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="${view.jsp}" />
works but stiil with the same warning Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Type "${view.jsp}" not found.
 - Type "${view.jsp}" not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the Eclipse IDE to develop for Liferay, I believe the following will be applicable. You can derive a patch for the software by following this bug tracker, or wait for this to be incorporated into the rolling release.

[JIRA issue: IDE-1855 - The jsp tag "param" has incorrect validation](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/IDE-1855)

**Eclipse Java IDE**

It sounds like you are affected by a known bug in the Liferay software. Work-around this behavior by taking the following steps in your IDE:

1. Open the Project Properties dialog.
2. Select the "Validation" page.
3. Mark the check box, "Enable project specific settings."
4. Find the, "JSP Reference Validation," setting and turn it off for manual and build.

[image: Eclipse IDE Work-Around for Liferay Bug]

Comment: The bug mentioned in this comment has been fixed and will be included in an upcoming release of Liferay IDE 2.2.2.